# C# Navigating through sites using HttpClient WP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, dotnet-httpclient

Been looking for a solution, but I havent been able to get a result that answers my questions.

I'm looking for a way to go through sites (basically read the html), using the HttpClient. I'm  making an app for windows phone, so some options may be disabled.

I want to make a program that goes to a site, logs in, and then is able to retrieve the access html source code.

So when I log in, a session id is saved in a CookieContainer, so I'll be able to access the sites that require login. How would I do this using the HttpClient :)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpClient manages authentication cookies automatically for you.  Just make sure you re-use the same HttpClient instance for multiple requests. Under the covers, HttpClient creates an instance of HttpClientHandler which has a CookieContainer.

Here is an example that logs into the NerdDinner site and retrieves a secured page.

```
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        // Create login payload
        var body = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
        {
            {"UserName",  "bob"},
            {"Password", "xyz"},
            {"RememberMe", "false"}
        };
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(body);

        // POST to login form
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://www.nerddinner.com/Account/LogOn?returnUrl=%2F", content);

        // Make new request to secured resource
        var myresponse = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.nerddinner.com/Dinners/My");

        var stringContent = await myresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Been trying this out, and it looks like I'm actually getting somewhere! :D

Comment: @Jazerix Don't forget to use the HTML Agility Pack as suggested by AMR